# Python CGI programming into MySQL

Tags: python, cgi

I have difficulties getting my sql inserting queries working.
    My Course_Id is currently an foreign key to another table CourseMaster.
Apparently all infos on CourseMaster have been input.

Student_Id forms input have also been a question mark to me. 
I have include hidden form type for hidId. Not to sure if it is right.
Please Advise.

```
import mysql.connector
import cgi
import cgitb;cgitb.enable()
import sys


print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"

#connection of my database
db = mysql.connector.connect( user='root',password = 'root',
                             host = 'localhost' ,port='8889',database = 'StudentData')


cursor = db.cursor()


form = cgi.FieldStorage()

id=""

first_name = ""

last_name = ""

residential_address = ""

phone_no = ""

Gender = ""

Course_Id = ""

if form.has_key("hidId"):
    id=form["hidId"].value
elif form.has_key("id"):
    id=form["id"].value

if form.has_key("first_name"):
    first_name = form["first_name"].value
    print "<p>name</p>"
    print first_name
if form.has_key("last_name"):
    last_name = form["last_name"].value
    print "<p>name</p>"
    print last_name
if form.has_key("residential_address"):
    residential_address = form["residential_address"].value
    print "<p>residential_address</p>"
    print residential_address
if form.has_key("phone_no"):
    phone_no = form["phone_no"].value
    print "<p>phone_no</p>"
    print phone_no
if form.has_key("Gender"):
    Gender = form["Gender"].value
    print "<p>Gender</p>"
    print Gender
if form.has_key("Course_Id"):
    Course_Id = form["Course_Id"].value
    print "<p>Course_Id</p>"
    print Course_Id

# Insert Data into Table StudentMaster
cursor.execute('''INSERT INTO StudentMaster
                  (Student_Id,Student_FirstName,Student_LastName,Course_Id,Gender,Residential_Address,PhoneNo)
                  VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)''',
                  (id,first_name,last_name,Course_Id,Gender,residential_address,phone_no))

cursor.lastrowid


db.commit()

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

**This was my error message.

```
**<class 'mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError'>: 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`studentdata`.`studentmaster`, CONSTRAINT `Course_ID Foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`Course_Id`) REFERENCES `CourseMaster` (`Course_Id`)) 
      args = (1452, '1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: ...rse_Id`) REFERENCES `CourseMaster` (`Course_Id`))', u'23000') 
      errno = 1452 
      message = '' 
      msg = u'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key ...rse_Id`) REFERENCES `CourseMaster` (`Course_Id`))' 
      sqlstate = u'23000'****
```

Answer (score 0):

If your IDs are all set correctly in `CourseMaster`, then it might be type issue. 
Check if the values from the forms should be converted from string to number.
try something like

```
Course_Id = int(Course_Id)
```

before executing your query